# Trouble in Qt plugin translation

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, translate

I have developed a Qt app and a plugin loaded with `QPluginLoader`.
I translated my plugin and created a .qm file, but plugin is not translated when I load this .qm file.

Here is my code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load(QLocale::system(), "tr", "_", 
        QString("translations/myplugin"));
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(&translator);
```

I confirmed `installTranslator` has succeeded, but no text is translated.
Could you tell me how to translate text in plugin?

Comment: Are you aware that all string you want translated have to be wrap by the tr() macro?

Comment: I surely wrapped  all string by tr().

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much from your question, but once you installed your translator, you need to call it everytime you need to translate a word. It will give you something like this :

```
QString word;
if (word.toTranslate()) //you want a word translated
    word = translator.tr("This will be translated");
else                    // you don't need a translation 
    word = "This will not be translated";
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need to pass QTranslator to my plugin?